# Occurence of elements in the file with c# and Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a file as

```
outlook temperature Humidity  Windy  PlayTennis
sunny      hot        high     false   N
sunny      hot        high     true    N
overcast   hot        high     false   P
rain       mild       high     false   P
rain       cool       normal   false   P
rain       cool       normal   true    N
```

I want to find occurence of each element e.g
sunny: 2
rain: 3
overcast:1
hot: 3
and so on

My code is:

```
    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    var text1 = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    string[] nonempty=lines.Where(s => s.Trim(' ')!="")
              .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ")).ToArray();       

    string[] colheader = null;       

    if (nonempty.Length > 0)
        colheader = nonempty[0].Split();
    else
        return;

    var linevalue = nonempty.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split());
    int colcount = colheader.Length;

    Dictionary<string, string> colvalue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colcount; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        foreach (string[] values in linevalue)
        {               
            if(! colvalue.ContainsKey(values[i]))
            {
                colvalue.Add(values[i],colheader[i]);                    
            }

         label2.Text = label2.Text + k.ToString();
        }           
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in colvalue)
    {
        label1.Text += pair.Key+ "\n";
    }
```

Output I get here is 
sunny
overcast
rain
hot 
mild
cool
N
P
true
false

I also want to find the occurence, which I am unable to get. Can u please help me out here.

Comment: Are there any problems in converting the file to an object list? It would be much easier to analyze the data

Answer (score 1):

This LINQ query will return `Dictionary<string, int>` which will contain each word in file as key, and word's occurrences as value:

```
var occurences = File.ReadAllLines(file).Skip(1) // skip titles line
    .SelectMany(l => l.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .GroupBy(w => w)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Usage of dictionary:

```
int sunnyOccurences = occurences["sunny"];

foreach(var pair in occurences)
    label1.Text += String.Format("{0}: {1}\n", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are implementing a simple Tag Cloud. I have used non-generic collection but you can replace it with generic. Replace the `HashTable` with `Dictionary`
Follow this code:

```
            Hashtable tagCloud = new Hashtable();
            ArrayList frequency = new ArrayList();
```

Read from a file and store it as array

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
            //use the specific delimiter
            char[] delimiter = new char[] { ' ' };
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.ToString().Length != 0)
                {
                    buffer.Append((" " + line.Trim()));
                }
            }
            string[] words = buffer.ToString().Trim().Split(delimiter);
```

Storing occurrence of each word.

```
  List<string> listOfWords = new List<string>(words);
            foreach (string i in listOfWords)
            {
                int c = 0;
                foreach (string j in words)
                {
                    if (i.Equals(j))
                        c++;
                }
                frequency.Add(c);
            }
```

Store as key value pair. Value will be word and key will be its occurrence

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfWords.Count; i++)
            {
                //use dictionary here
                tagCloud.Add(listOfWords[i], (int)frequency[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the keyword and a count of how many times they appear in the file, then lazyberezovsky's solution is about as elegant of a solution as you will find.  But if you need to do any other metrics on the file's data, then I would load the file into a collection that keeps your other metadata intact.

Something simple like:

```
var forecasts = File.ReadAllLines(file).Skip(1) // skip the header row
    .Select(line => line.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) // split the line into an array of strings
    .Select (f =>
    new
    {
        Outlook = f[0],
        Temperature = f[1],
        Humidity = f[2],
        Windy = f[3],
        PlayTennis = f[4]
    });
```

will give you an `IEnumerable<>` of an anonymous type that has properties that can be queried.

For example if you wanted to see how many times "sunny" occurred in the Outlook then you could just use LINQ to do this:

```
var count = forecasts.Count( f => f.Outlook == "sunny");
```

Or if you just wanted the list of all outlooks you could write:

```
var outlooks = forecasts.Select(f => f.Outlook).Distinct();
```

Where this is useful is when you want to do more complicated queries like "How many rainy cool days are there?

```
var count = forecasts.Count (f => f.Outlook == "rain" && f.Temperature == "cool");
```

Again if you just want all words and their occurrence count, then this is overkill.

Comment: I want to do exactly what u telling..
i got it..but I am unable to display dynamic value..

Now i want output as( from the first output, it should loop with every other element to make a set of two frequent set)

element:occurence

sunny,hot:2
sunny,high:2
sunny,false:1
sunny,n:2
sunny,p:0
rain,hot:0
rain,high:1
rain,false:2
rain,n:0
rain,p:2
hot,high:2
hot,false:1
hot,n:2
hot,p:0
and so on..

I need to write var count = forecasts.Count (f => f.Outlook == "rain" && f.Temperature == "cool");
for every statement.
can u pls suggest what shud i do to make it dynamic.

Comment: Just do a nested foreach loop on your outlook and temperature collections and replace the hard coded strings in the above statement with your loop variables.  i.e. foreach (var outlook in forecasts.Select(f => f.Outlook).Distinct()) { foreach ( var temp in forecasts.Select(f => f.Temperature).Distinct()) { var count = forecasts.Count(f => f.Outlook == outlook && f.Temperature == temp); } }